# Vivaldi DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG but can access sites with Chrome

Tags: dns, browser, vivaldi

Vivaldi is my main web browser. I just restarted my PC and Vivaldi now won't load web pages.

For every page I try, first I was getting the error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN and now seem to be getting DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG.

The thing is, all of the solutions I have found seem to indicate that this is a broader DNS problem, not just a problem with Vivaldi, however I am currently able to access the internet with no problems with Chrome.

Any ideas what could be causing *only* Vivaldi to be having this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue that involves the browser's default DNS/Proxy configuration.  Solutions I see:
 1. Ensure that there is no specified proxy or DNS under the "Settings" tab of the browser.
 2. If there is no proxy or DNS, set your own DNS servers to the ones that Chrome is using.
 3. If all of the following fail, there is probably an issue with your system firewall blocking inbound and/or outbound DNS traffic.
A good way to determine if this is NOT a DNS issue, type an IP Address into the browser and see if it will load the page (example: http://1.1.1.1)